# How to use React-Bootstrap in react.rb

Tags: react-bootstrap, react.rb

I'm using react.rb in my project, And I want to use bootstrap too.
I found the React-Bootstrap,but don't know how to use it in react.rb.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @catmando share the answer.

First, define a wrapper:

```
class RB < React::NativeLibrary
  imports ReactBootstrap
end
```

Then, using it like this

```
RB.Button(bs_style: :default){"My Button"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new way of doing this, simply add
`require 'reactrb/auto-import'` to components.rb then all JS libraries that are required will be automatically imported into the Ruby namespace so after that you can access the JS components directly. See an example here: https://github.com/barriehadfield/reactrb-showcase#working-with-react-bootstrap